# How to show CSS in current @media query in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, media-queries, firebug

In the Chrome DevTools I can inspect an element to see its CSS and the related media query:

[image: Chrome DevTools showing the media query related to a CSS rule]

As you can see in the *Styles* panel, Chrome intelligently shows my current media with `min-width: 1200px`. However, Chrome is currently sucking lots of my computer's memory and therefore I have to switch back to Firefox, i.e. Firebug).

However, Firebug misses the media query part:

[image: Firebug missing the media query for the CSS rule]

Is there any possibility/extension in Firefox that can show the CSS rules along with their current media queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebug doesn't have that feature implemented. It was requested in [issue 5329](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/5329), though Firebug is discontinued now, so it won't be implemented anymore.

Though the *Rules* side panel of the Firefox DevTools does show @media queries.
[image: *Rules* side panel in Firefox DevTools displaying @media query]

To get them displayed uncheck the option *Show original sources* within the options panel.
[image: Unchecked *Show original sources* option within Firefox DevTools]

As [upcoming versions of Firebug will integrate into the DevTools][4], they will inherit this feature.

Comment: Shouldn't it be turned on for the media query info to appear?

Comment: No, because the original sources may not be CSS but a preprocessed language like SASS or LESS.

Comment: This may actually have changed already, I didn't check lately.

Answer (score 9):

**Update 2019**

To show current media queries open settings (F1 from dev tools) and check "Show Browser Styles" under the **Inspector** section.

[image]

The media query will be shown just to the right of the file name and line number.

[image]