# Display currently active media query rule in Firebug

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Is it possible in Firebug (Firefox Web Development add-on) to display which media query rules are currently active?

E.g.: I monitor a **div** element as usual. Then I scale the browser window to be smaller than 400px (or use the Firefox web dev screen size tool). I want to see a list of rules that are currently active for this element like this.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  div { float: left }
}
```

Is that possible with Firebug or a similar tool?

Comment: I don't use Firebug, but in most other browsers, the developer tools will not only show you what styles are applied but the source of those styles as well. In Chrome, the rule in effect is in a section that shows the selector.

Comment: In Firebug not applied rules are strikethrough and if you are'nt using a minified file you will the line number next to the rule.

Comment: Yeah I know all that, but searching for the active styles can get quite time consuming in a web site with lots of styles, even more if some of these styles are from multiple CSS sources, some of them may be minified. So I'm searching for a quick and to-the-point tool.

Comment: take a look at this already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870059/how-to-show-css-in-current-media-query-in-firefox

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this, to show what mediaquery is currently working, please update with your mediaqueries:

The div will print what mediaquery is 'on', so you can hide the div, and use it only for development purposes.

```css
@media  (min-width: 400px) {
  .mediaq:after {
    content:'min 400' 
  }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .mediaq:after {
    content:'min 800' 
  }
}
@media  (min-width: 1200px) {
  .mediaq:after {
    content:'min 1200' 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mediaq"></div>
```

Comment: Very nice, but not exactly what I was looking for. I need a tool for an already made CSS.